# Media Content editor tinyMCE for cakephp 3.7

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, editor

I'm using cakephp 3.7. I tried to get tinymce working, by 2 differents ways but it doesn't work. First I tried to adapte the former cakephp 2 steps to make it work as shown in the cakephp documentation here "https://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/04/11/Helper-TinyMCE-for-CakePHP-2.html", it worked in a previous project where i used cakephp 2, but here it didn't work. Secondly I followed an other tutorial suggesting to`enter code here` use tinymce inside cakephp 3.7 's plugin folder just like a plugin, but still not working. Any help about how to install tinymce for cakephp 3.7?
N.B: I got my cakephp 3.7 through composer as well as all the other plugins i used, except tinymce that i can't get with composer. 
I'm having this error : Method App\View\Helper\TinymceHelper::domId does not exist [CORE/src/View/Helper.php, line.
Thanks in advance.

1. I downloaded tinymce and set it up in the webroot/js folder
2. In the AppController.php  I added `public $helpers = ['tinymce.tinymce'];`
3. In the view where to display the tinymce editor I added in the relevant text area

   ```
   <?php echo $this->Tinymce->input('content', 
          array('label' => 
            'Content'),array('language'=>'en'),'bbcode'); 
    ?>
   ```

   This my the head in tinymceHelper.php

```
      use Cake\View\Helper;
      use Cake\View\StringTemplateTrait;

            class TinymceHelper extends Helper 
         {

        // Take advantage of other helpers
        public $helpers = array('Js', 'Html', 'Form');
       ...}
```

Or may be you also know another content editor more relevant to cakephp 3.7. Thanks you guys !

Comment: Where did you get this helper from?

Comment: Hi Greg Schmidt, just as I stated in above, the use of tinymceHelper.php is part of tinymce implementation for cakephp 2, according to cakephp 2 documentation like here in this link https://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/04/11/Helper-TinyMCE-for-CakePHP-2.html .

Comment: You can't just drop a CakePHP 2 helper into a CakePHP 3 application and expect it to work. The internal architecture of these things has changed substantially.

Comment: Yeah I know,I know the cakephp 3 's architecture by heart which is completely different to the version 2, and the composer dependencies manager it allows. But when you're struggling to hit the right point, desperately trying to make it work for more than 3 days without success, you try all the cars and even the wayward bicycles. If you have anything that can help,  I'm here @Greg Schmidt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a certain time of research and with the suggestion of @Greg Schmidt, I got the Ckeditor not as a plugin but inside the js folder.
1- I refered to it in the AppController.php with

public $helpers = ['CkEditor.Ck'];

2- In the media.ctp I called the Ckeditor in the head of the file by "

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('ckeditor/ckeditor');?>
```

(This is very mandatory because without this call cakephp 3.x will only display a 
      blank textarea).

3- In the relevant form element where to load the ckeditor I used the syntax 
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SujUS.png)

`<?= echo $this->Ck->input('Media_Content', array('class', 'ckeditor); ?>`

4- In the relevant layout I added 
  Html->script('https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full/ckeditor.js'); ?> just as Greg Schmidt suggested.
And the Ckeditor shows up !!!

Answer (score 0):

I switched from TinyMCE to CKEDITOR. I don't have any kind of helper, just:

- load the JS in the layout (`echo $this->Html->script('https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full/ckeditor.js');`)
- put relevant classes (e.g. `wysiwyg_simple` or `wysiwyg_advanced`) on inputs as required (`echo $this->Form->input('description', ['class' => 'wysiwyg_simple']);`)
- have an initialization function as below, called from `onReady` (and also whenever dynamic content that might contain a textarea is loaded into the page)

```
if (typeof CKEDITOR !== 'undefined') {
    for(name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
    }
    CKEDITOR.replaceAll(function (textarea, config) {
        if (jQuery(textarea).hasClass('wysiwyg_advanced')) {
            config.toolbar = [
                {
                    name: 'clipboard',
                    items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']
                },
                {name: 'editing', items: ['SpellChecker', 'Scayt']},
                {name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
                {name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak']},
                '/',
                {
                    name: 'basicstyles',
                    items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
                },
                {
                    name: 'paragraph',
                    items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
                        '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']
                },
                '/',
                {name: 'styles', items: ['Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
                {name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
                {name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About']},
                {name: 'document', items: ['Source']}
            ];
        } else if (jQuery(textarea).hasClass('wysiwyg_simple')) {
            config.toolbar = [
                {name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
                {
                    name: 'basicstyles',
                    items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
                },
                {name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList']},
                {name: 'styles', items: ['Format']}
            ];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        config.resize_dir = 'both';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Greg Schmidt for your time to help, I post the outcome in the bottom for stackoverflow says it's too long for comment so I post it in tne "answer field' although is not an answer but a report.

Comment: I’ve tried what you said and in the relevant form element I put just as you suggested “ echo $this->Html->input('Media_content', ['class' => 'wysiwyg_simple']);
“ and I got the error “ Warning (512): Method Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper:: input does not exist [CORE/src/View/Helper.php, line 11” and the textarea doesn’t even appear.

Comment: But when I use “echo $this->Ck->input('Media_content');” whith Ck standing for Ckeditor, the texarea does appear but is running without the javascript code you provided to add management features to the ckeditor, and as a result I can’t manage the content in that textarea, no icon appears in the textarea.

Comment: You’ve not also mentioned whether you downloaded your ckeditor inside the plugin folder or in the webroot/js folder or downloaded it with composer. I downloaded mine with composer and set this snippet of json code in my composer.json file "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "CkEditor\\": "./plugins/CkEditor/src/"
        }
    },

with my composer.json file located in the root of my application

Comment: Oops, I meant `Form->input`, not `Html->input`. Fixed above. And as I said, I used no plugin for this, but rather loading the ckeditor JavaScript from their CDN, plus my own block of custom JS to initialize. So there's nothing related to composer in my solution.

Comment: thanks for the help, you put me on the right path with Ckeditor, but I used a different step, because Ckeditor was not being reached by controller for cakephp 3.7's composer. But I learnt from the ideas you provided to fix it. Thanks. I will make a description of what I did for cakephp 3.7 as soon as I recovered my lost days.